# Problem with hosting two websites on one IIS server

Tags: domain-name-system, iis

On my Windows Home Server (Windows Server 2003 really) there is a default web site (enabling remote access etc.) and I'm trying to setup a second site (both on port 80). The default site is using xxx.homeserver.com as its address and the new one is using blog.xxx.no. What happens is that the default site works as expected (and as before), but when I try to access the new one **without** specifying the document (ie. index.htm) it access the default site. But if I add the document (index.htm) it access it correctly... I have setup the default document to be index.htm and it's on top of the list. I have also set the correct host header for both of them.

Any idea on why this is happening?

Answer (score 3):

You need to configure host headers on the second web site (I would recommend setting them on both web sites).

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/324287

Comment: Forgot to mention that I have already done so.

Answer (score 0):

You might check to ensure your "default document" is indeed index.htm as you expect.

Comment: It is set correct. But the weird thing here is that when I access the new site without "index.htm" it goes to the old site...

Comment: You might check against the settings/configuration for the specific virtual domain itself - just in case it is somehow different.

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: You have a virtual domain configuration for your blog.xxx.no right?

Comment: If you by "virtual domain" mean "virtual directory", then yes.

Comment: Ok, is there anything between the server and the web browser (namely proxies)? What is the network configuration between the systems?

Comment: The DNS is with a registrar, created a CNAME redirect to my IP (static). On my side there is a router with port forwarding (80) to my IIS server (Win2k3). To test this I remote into work (RDP) and then open the browser against the address.

Comment: Why do you need to RDP into the work system (and possibly circumvent the Internet) when you have a CNAME set up (assuming this is for access through the Internet)?

Comment: If I access it from my computer it looks like it is picked up by my router and so it believes that I am trying to logon on to it.

Comment: "If I access it from my computer it looks like it is picked up by my router and so it believes that I am trying to logon on to it." That does not seem to make any sense. Maybe you should provide some information on how your web application should work?

Comment: There is no web application, it's just a static web page...

Comment: You need to check your server logs to see what it is picking up from the web browser/client. If it looks correct, then it's your server configuration.